# Unable to start AMQP service in IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, amqp

I have installed IBM MQ (version: 8.0.0.5) in in my local windows machine (Windows 7 professional x64). I did following steps to enable the AMQP service.

Went trough the default configuration setup wizard and post card test is also done to check whether the installation is successful or not. All went as expected.

Then I went through the following steps to enable the AMQP service.

1. End the queue manager. (endmqm QMAN_NAME)
2. Enable the command level. (strmqm -e CMDLEVEL=801 QMAN_NAME)
3. Run queue manager. (runmqsc QMAN_NAME)

Afterwards i tried to bring up the AMQP service using MQ Explorer. Status field of the service changed to "Running" and **immediately automatically changed back to "Stopped"** (As shown in the below image)

[Output of the start service attempt from the MQ Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF2U2.png)

Then tried using command line (As shown in the following lines)

- runmqdc QMAN_NAME (Start the command line)
- START SERVICE (SYSTEM.AMQP.SERVICE)

[Output of the start service command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1adb1.png)

I tried with few different windows machines (Including a VM) and with a linux machine as well. Same result occurred in every attempt.

I wasted more than two days to find out a solution for this matter. I would be really grateful if you could give me a clue.

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed IBM Websphere application server (version: 8.0.0.5)

You mean WAS v8.0.0.5 or MQ 8.0.0.5?  If you mean MQ 8.0.0.5 did you read this IBM blog posting: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/MQ_support_for_MQ_Light_released_in_8_0_0_4?lang=en

In particular it says:

> If you have installed MQ fixpack 8.0.0.2, 8.0.0.3, or 8.0.0.4 on top
>   of an existing MQ 8 installation and upgraded the queue manager to
>   command level 801 or higher you will see some of the new AMQP-related
>   objects appear. They cannot be used without performing a fresh install
>   of 8.0.0.4 or later.

So, did you do a fresh install of MQ 8.0.0.4 or higher?

Comment: I am really new to this context. I actually setup this in a separate fresh windows 7 virtual machine.

Comment: So this is not a case where upgrade happened.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to start AMQP exactly as you describe (on v9).  Opened an IBM ETR and an apar fix was created.  The controlamqp_mqm.sh script has a defect in it that clashes with .bashrc.  Not sure if this is your issue, but it fixed my queuemanager/amqp.

Comment: It would be good to note the APAR number in this case so others could review it if they think it may be the cause of the problem they are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the MQ and amqp error logs . the amqp error logs can also be found in the same MQ error log folder.
Did you define any AMQP channel ?If you had already defined, check whether the port is already being used by any other process.